# Puzzle: find number of cubes with 1 red face

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

### Objective

Find an algorithm to count the number of cubes with at least one red side.

### Puzzle

I have a puzzle that goes by the following:

> Imagine you have a cube. Someone picks up that cube, and drops it in a
>   bucket of red paint. The whole cube is now painted red.
>
> Then that person cuts through the cube in all three dimensions `N` times.
>
> `N` is the number of times that the cube is cut in each dimension.
>
> The objective is, given the number of cuts done (N) to find out how
>   many small cubes have at least one red face.

### Expected results

Following are two expected results from the problem (the only cases I have):

N = 2 --> 26

N = 4 --> 98

### Problem

I am sure there must be some mathematical formula to achieve this, but I am completely unaware of it. I need an algorithm to get me started on this puzzle!

### Aftermath Solution

As promised, here is the algorithm in JavaScript. Turns out it was pretty simple in the end !

A simple version would be the following:

```
function countCubes(cuts){
  if(cuts === 0)
    return 1;

  return (6 * cuts * cuts) + 2;
}
```

However, for those savvy of tech, I also have a shorter version with the latest ECMA6. I know this probably doesn't belong here, but a promise is a promise !

I hope you enjoy!

```
/**
 * Given a cube painted in red and sliced `N` times in the XYZ axis, this function (that should be named countCubes instead of countSquares) counts the number
 * of small cubes with at least one red face.
 *
 * This function avoids the use of `pow` on purpose. See references for more info. 
 *
 * Special thanks to the people in math.exchange, they were kind and awesome.
 *
 * @param    {number}    cuts    The number of 3D cuts done to the painted cube.
 * @returns  {number}    The number of cubes with at least one red face.
 * @see      {@link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874787/puzzle-find-number-of-cubes-with-1-red-face} for the mathematical algorithm behind the scenes. 
 * @see      {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions} for information about Arrow functions in ECMA6
 * @see      {@link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382967/is-math-pow-more-expensive-than-multiplication-using-temporary-assignments} Comparison of multiply VS `pow`
 */
const countSquares = cuts => cuts ? (6 * cuts * cuts) + 2 : 1;
```

PS:

- Special kudos to all the kind people in math.exchange that helped. I was not expecting such a warm welcome for sure!

Comment: There are $N^3$ little cubes.  if you remove all the ones with paint on them, you get $(N-2)^3$ little cubes.

Comment: Do you $N$ times horizontally, then $N$ times vertically, then $N$ times "the other" vertically, giving $(N+1)^3$ little cubes in total? Or do you do something else (in which case I wouldn't call the small resulting pieces "cubes")?

Comment: I updated the description to be more detailed, I hope it is better now ! Added expected results!

Comment: Sorry, I assumed we were cutting into $N$ cubes in each direction (hence $N-1$ cuts).  That is, your $N$ corresponds to my $N+1$.  The answer to the problem the way you phrased it is $(N+1)^3-(N-1)^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming $N\geq1$.) After $N$ cuts, there are $(N+1)^3$ small cubes in total. If you strip away the outer layer of cubes with paint on them, there are $(N-1)^3$ cubes left. That means that the number of cubes you stripped away is $$(N+1)^3-(N-1)^3=6N^2+2$$Alternative solution: There are a total of $6(N+1)^2$ painted small faces. There are eight small cubes that have three faces painted (the corners), so we must subtract a total of $16$ to account for that (they make up $24$ painted faces, buy only eight cubes with red on them). There are also $12(N-1)$ small cubes that have two faces each painted, so we need to subtract $12N-12$ for that. In total
$$
6(N+1)^2-12(N-1)-16=6N^2+2
$$
small cubes with paint on one or more faces.

Comment: Wow, I would not have done that ! Great idea, thanks !

Comment: I would like to add, that if `N = 0` the result is 1 :D

Comment: I shall update this question soon with the answer !